# how to install ngMapHilight in existing angular project?

Tags: angular

i have downloaded the `angular-maphilight.js`  and `angular-maphilight.min.js` from `git`
and put inside my angular project but its didn't worked for me. whenever i put `ngMaphilight` user `angula.module()` it shows error Module `ngMapHilight` is not available!

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[ng-maphilight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-maphilight)

```
npm i ng-maphilight
```

and add **MaphilightModule** to the imports array.

In your component class, define a config property.

In your template:

```
<maphilight id="statesMap" [config]="config">
    <img src="assets/states_imgmap.gif">

<map>
    <area shape="poly" ...>
</map>
```

Comment: what is included in the config?